# Python methods hint is gone after not completed pyannotate

Tags: python, annotations, pylance

I develop the python module. I store it in "site-packages" folder.
Recently I turned on "strict" Pylance type checking and saw the error "Stub file not found" I tried to get rid of it using pyannotate.
Since my tests does not cover all the methods of this module, annotation is not completed. I see that the error is not gone completely.

But after that I faced with the strange issue. I try to call a module's method out of the external .py file (out of VSCode), so i write smth like

```
import MyModule
MyModule.
```

After typing '.', I expect that the hint appearing with all the methods of the module. But I don't see my methods. I only see some dunder methods like `__dict__` `__doc__` `__file__` etc.

I used the following annotation procedure:

1. Install pyannotate: `pip install pyannotate`
2. Execute the code:

```
    from pyannotate_runtime import collect_types
    collect_types.init_types_collection()
    # collect_types.start()
    with collect_types.collect():
        __main__()
    # collect_types.stop()
    collect_types.dump_stats("type_info.json")
```

3. Run command shell and type `pyannotate type_info.json`

So, is it possible to revert somehow my annotation, if it is not completed?

I tried to remove the file `type_info.json`, which i generated, but with no success.
I also tried to remove the folder `__pycache__`